# Spring Boot & Jackson not serialising timestamp correctly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that is returning a map from a `@RestController` that is being serialised using the default Spring Boot Jackson configuration.  All is fine, except the map includes a `java.sql.Timestamp` which is being serialised to milliseconds:

```
{"timestamp":1428401341884}
```

I want this to be serialised as a text representation, so I have configured the option using

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

in my `application.properties`.

Now, if I have a unit test that just autowires the ObjectMapper from my Spring configuration as below then it works, the config flag works and I can switch between text and numeric representation of the timestamp.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = [Application])
@WebAppConfiguration
class JacksonJsonSerialisationTest {

    @Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper

    @Test public void serialiseTimestamp() throws Exception {
        Map test = [ timestamp: new java.sql.Timestamp( new Date().getTime() ) ]
        println objectMapper.writeValueAsString( test )
    }
}
```

However, when I check my controller, this flag is being ignored and the timestamp is always being serialised as a numeric format.

Anyone come across this or know what I am missing?

Comment: Are you using `@EnableWebMvc` annotation? If so, that's the cause of it, as you can see here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2566

Comment: I'm not adding it explicitly @jbarrueta - I am using the '@EnableAutoConfiguration' - doesn't Spring Boot basically add it by default when spring mvc is on the classpath?

Comment: Thanks @jbarrueta - your comment pointed me in the right direction - I was extending WebMvcConfigurationSupport for my config class, so the config wasn't being picked up - I had to explicitly define my ObjectMapper and converter beans and then use the configureMessageConverters method to register it.  All working now!

Comment: I was replying now, good to hear it's all working now!

Comment: @jbarrueta - strange follow up question.. My original controller is handling the Timestamp correctly (controller just gets map from DB and returns basically), but I have another controller which is doing the same, but with a different response structure from the DB and those Timestamps are not being converted to text.. any ideas?

Comment: how does the Timestamp response looks ? Is the same  java.sql.Timestamp object? or is it different?

Comment: Yeah, all are just instances of java.sql.Timestamp - only real difference is difference in the nested structure (Maps/Lists)

Comment: The nested structure shouldn't matter, sounds like you're not using the same `ObjectMapper` and/or `MessageConverters `in your controllers.

Comment: Yeah, not sure how that could be possible? looking at the logs from the two requests it looks like the converters are the same (both say `using org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@59ab4339`) - is it even possible for the two controllers to have the same converter but different ObjectMappers?

Comment: No, they shouldn't the same `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` should use the same converter. Any Jackson annotations you have? Maybe the getter method of your object returns `long`?

Comment: Nope, its all just plain Map/List stuff (its in groovy) so no pojos/annotations etc.  Both cases confirmed as java.sql.Timestamp..

Comment: Ok, I think I should just stay off StackOverflow..  The problem was actually because I tweaked the configuration of the MessageConverters and my custom jackson converter was added after the default converter so was no longer solving the original problem - but the first controller continued to work because some other code had since changed which basically just called `toString()` on the dates!  Fixed the order of the MessageConverters and all working again.. Thanks again @jbarrueta!